# VOIP/SIP Call Hold related questions

Tags: sip, voip, ims

1) How many types of call holds are there in SIP/VOIP?
2) Does SDP parameter changes for reinvite during call hold?
3) Does RTP packets flow during call hold?

Answer (score 0):

> 1. How many types of call holds are there in SIP/VOIP?

Two main types are recognised, `Attended` and `Blind`.

- Attended is where you call and speak to the transfer destination first.
- Blind is where you instruct the transferee to call the destination without the introduction.

> 2. Does SDP parameter changes for reinvite during call hold?

Normally yes. The media flow [SDP attribute](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4566#section-8.2.4) will typically change from `sendrecv` to `sendonly`/`recvonly`/`inactive` depending on how call hold is implemented.

Another common way to put a call on hold is to play on hold music and in that case the SDP may not need to change at all. It's a simple substitution of audio capture input for music.

> 3. Does RTP packets flow during call hold?

Depends on how the call hold is implemented. If the media flow attribute is used then RTP will normally stop flowing in one or both directions.

If it's done with music on hold RTP will keep flowing in the original manner.

Comment: 1) You are correct...is there any other way apart from reinvite and update we can put call on hold ?    2) I meant apart from sendrecv/sendonly/recvonly/inactive is there any other changes in sdp compare to sdp in original invite send to initiate call?   3) I heard when call is on hold, rtcp packets flows to keep link alive, is it?

Comment: Yes. As I stated you can just start playing music on hold. But other than there are different scenarios that might use REFER or UPDATE requests. "On Hold" isn't an official part of the SIP standard so it can mean different things to different people. If you call me and I transfer you to a music on hold server it will be termed as being "put on hold" but at the SIP level it was a transfer using a REFER request. Also see https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7088.